# pg_dumpall пользователь "oleg34" не прошёл проверку подлинности

Tags: postgresql

Выполняю команду `pg_dumpall > asd.out`

Дальше просят ввести пароль, но он от пользователя windows, а не postgres.

Можно ли выполнить дамп, зная пользователя postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел. Нужно ввести`--username=postgres` и затем пароль несколько раз.

```
pg_dumpall > asd.out --username=postgres
```

Comment: Обычно ключи пишутся до перенаправления результатов в файл, интересно как оно у вас умудряется работать после ...